# Multiple loggers not working in lua logging module

Tags: logging, nginx, lua

I am running lua script inside nginx. But the logging module is not working correctly for multiple loggers. Below is the code:

```
log_mod1 = require "logging.file"                                                                                                                                                                             
log_mod2 = require "logging.rolling_file"
rlogger = log_mod2("/var/log/nginx/req.log", 1024 * 1024 * 1024, 5, "%message\n")
rrlogger = log_mod1("/var/log/nginx/info-%s.log", "%Y-%m-%d")
```

The second logger rrlogger is not outputting anything to its corresponding file. Is it the case that logging module only allows 1 logger to be instantiated and used (It doesn't seem so by looking at the documentation of the logging module - http://neopallium.github.io/lualogging/manual.html)? I have also tried using rolling_file for both the loggers but still the result is the same.

When I tried reversing the order of the loggers, then the logger defined first was working correctly and the second logger didn't.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with two `logging.file` loggers? What version of lualogging is this? Can you create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for this?